# how to use options from showMessageDialog to do things?

Tags: java, jbutton, joptionpane

I am making a game on Java and i am doing a character selection menu. Within that menu i have the characters and if the user clicks on certain character a  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog appears shows the stats of the character. So my question is if the person clicks "ok" which is automatically created when using the function how to i get that to select the character?

```
JButton chuck = new JButton(new ImageIcon("8bitChuckNorris.jpg"));//this part of program runs this if user picks lizard
chuck.setSize(210,175); //sets size of button
chuck.setLocation(300,317); //sets location of button
chuck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\tSTATS\nAttack\ndefence\nspecial");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a method that the `actionPerformed` method can call after the `JOptionPane` can call

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Comment: Sir or mam, i do not mean any disrespect obviously you know what your talking about but I'm a rookie, I was not going to take it to that extent and I don't quite understand anything you just said.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't be using `null` layouts (or absolute layouts) as you've not taken into account the fact that no two systems are exactly the same, meaning that all your wonderful work and placing your components in pixel locations/sizes could be undone the moment you run it on another system...

Comment: oh ok! wait so then what other way can I do it then?

Comment: Make use of one or more appropriate [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would probably be to provide a method that the `ActionListener` can call after the 
the option pane is closed, for example...

```
chuck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\t                  STATS\nAttack\ndefence\nspecial");
        characterSelected("chuck"); // Pass whatever you need to identify the character
    }
});
```

**Updated**

It would be easier to use `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` as it will actually return a `int` result representing the option that the user selected (or -1 if they dismissed the dialog without selecting anything)

```
 switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "\t\t                  STATS\nAttack\ndefence\nspecial", "Character", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)) {
     case JOptionPane.OK:
         // Process selection...
         break;
 }
```

Comment: i think your misinterpreting my question. You know how JOptionPane.showMessageDialog creates a popup and in that popup it creates a ok button a and a close button on the top right. I want to use that ok as the character selected

Comment: Easier to use something like `JOptionPane@showConfirmDialog`